# Which way of expressing a Card is more efficient? Integer, Struct or Class?

Tags: class, optimization, visual-c++, data-structures

For performance critical operations, is there a difference in expressing a Card in the form of an Integer/Enum, Struc or a Class?

Integer:

```
0 => Spade King
1 => Spade Queen
2 => Spade Jack 
. 
. 
. 
51 => Club Two
```

Struc:

```
 Struct Card
 {
      Suit GivenSuit;
      Rank GivenRank;

      Some functions... 
 }`
```

Class:

```
 Class Card
 {
      Card();

      Suit GivenSuit;
      Rank GivenRank;

      Some functions... 
 }
```

Comment: If you don't know then you need to keep it flexible.  Start with the class so you can easily extend it, with accessor functions to get the properties.  Very high odds you'll discover it just doesn't matter since it is already plenty fast enough.  If not then use bit-fields next.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will look into that option.

Answer (score 0):

How about enum and pair.

```
enum CardsValues {
  Ace = 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9
  Jack = 10,
  Queen,
  King,
}

enum CardColour {
 Spade, ...
}
std::pair<CardValue, CardColour> theCard;
```

Comment: Does a pair with 2 enums compute twice as long as just an Integer? For a high amount of read/write operations, will this cause a significant difference in performance?

Comment: That is very implementation, optimisation and tweeking dependend, the pair could be 2 char, so be shorter than an int, but in reality you only need one char to encode it, 2 bits for colour and 4 bits for value.

Comment: I see... I didn't thought of using char at all. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If the cards have been defined as integers in the calling class, it may be a tad bit more efficient with respect to access time than accessing a class from outside the calling class.

But this maybe micro-optimizing your solution and a trade off of functionality v/s efficiency in terms of nanosecond.

Not entirely sure what your application is, but if you're coding a generic deck of cards, it would make more sense with respect to OOP design principles to use a class Card. Using integers will make your class non-reusable and brittle.

Comment: My application involves using monte carlo simulation to derive an estimated winning odds. The simulation takes quite a toll in the compute time and I was wondering whether the way I defined `Card` will be one of the causes.